# Как убить процесс, который слушает порт (например, nginx)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, процесс, port

У меня есть процесс, который слушает порт. Как убить его одной командой? Предположим, это `nginx` на 80 порту

Comment: Если вы знаете название процесса, то можно убить просто по названию

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sudo kill -9 $(sudo lsof -t -i:80)
```

Answer (score 0):

Linux only — `fuser`:

```
fuser -k 80/tcp
```